# struct name does not name a type

Tags: c++, struct, arduino

I see there are a couple of Q&A in this topic but I still can't find the clue to my issue. I must admit I am pretty new to c++, so this might be the root cause.

Ok, so I am trying to declare a new type like :

```
struct measurement_t
{
  int sensorID;
  int sensorData;
  measurement_t(int ID, int Data)
  {
    sensorID = ID;
    sensorData = Data;
  }
};
```

and my project contains a method, that should return this type of data:

```
measurement_t getLightSensorData()
{
    ...
}
```

when I try to compile the code I got error : error: 'measurement_t' does not name a type

What I also find very strange is that the error line the compiler reports is the line number of the first #define statement at the very beginning of the code :

```
#define CE_PIN  7
```

If I simply change the method to void, the the project compiles (useless, though).

I also tried returning pointer by specifying measurement_t * as return type but the result is the same. Tried remove constructor from struct, same result again.

Can someone please help me to understand what the problem is here ?

The minimal version of the code that reproducing the same issue is:

```
struct measurement_t
{
  int sensorID;
  int sensorData;
  measurement_t(int ID, int Data)
  {
    sensorID = ID;
    sensorData = Data;
  }
};


measurement_t getLightSensorData()
{
  int sensorValue = 1;
  measurement_t m(1, sensorValue);
  return m;
}
```

[image]

For reference, this is intended to be an arduino sketch, and the full code is as below:

```
#include "RF24.h"
#include <SPI.h>
#include "printf.h"

#define CE_PIN  7
#define CS_PIN  8
#define LIGHTSENSOR_PIN A0

RF24 myRadio(CE_PIN, CS_PIN);
byte rxAddr[6] = { 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0F };

unsigned long currentMillis;
unsigned long prevMillis;
unsigned long txIntervalMillis = 3000; // send once per second
unsigned long loopSleepMillis = 200;

struct measurement_t
{
  int sensorID;
  int sensorData;
  measurement_t(int ID, int Data)
  {
    sensorID = ID;
    sensorData = Data;
  }
};

// the setup routine runs once when you press reset:
void setup()
{
  Serial.println(">>> Initializing...");
  Serial.begin(115200);
  printf_begin();
  bool radioOk = myRadio.begin();  // Start up the physical nRF24L01 Radio
  if (radioOk) Serial.println("     Radio initialized");
  else Serial.println("     ERROR initializing radio !");
  myRadio.setChannel(120);  // Above most Wifi Channels
  myRadio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_HIGH);
  myRadio.setRetries(15, 15);
  myRadio.openWritingPipe(rxAddr); // Use the first entry in array 'addresses' (Only 1 right now)
  Serial.println("<<< Done initialization");
}

// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop()
{
  currentMillis = millis();
  if (currentMillis - prevMillis >= txIntervalMillis)
  {
    transmitData(getLightSensorData());
    prevMillis = millis();
  }
  delay(loopSleepMillis);
}

measurement_t getLightSensorData()
{
  int sensorValue = analogRead(LIGHTSENSOR_PIN);
  measurement_t m(1, sensorValue);
  return m;
}

void transmitData(measurement_t data)
{
  myRadio.stopListening();
  Serial.print("Transmitting data...");
  bool writeOK = myRadio.write(&data, sizeof(data));
  if (writeOK)
  {
    Serial.println("OK");
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println(F("no response"));
    //myRadio.printDetails();
  }
}
```

Comment: Circular inclusion problem?

Comment: Thanks, but I do not think this issue has anything to do with inclusion

Comment: What's the full error message?

Comment: @LászlóFrank Well, read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-header-include-circular-dependencies) to be sure that isn't your problem.

Comment: @melpomene : 6:1: error: 'measuremant_t' does not name a type

Comment: That's not the full message. Line 6 of what?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ : but the error line is not the #include, but the #define. How is it related to include ? Moreover, the included headers a standard libraries, surely not including my simple, first and new code.

Comment: @LászlóFrank Create a [MCVE] that reproduces your problem, and post that one in your question please.

Comment: Are you absolutely *sure* you're looking at the correct file?  The error message doesn't relate to a header that's being pulled in?

Comment: @melpomene : yes, it is the full message indeed. Line 6 of the full code I inlcuded with the post. But more precisely, there re other errors, you probably mean that :-)
6:1: error: 'measurement_t' does not name a type  
7:19: error: 'measurement_t' was not declared in this scope  
7:19: error: variable or field 'transmitData' declared void  
51:34: error: 'transmitData' was not declared in this scope  
51:33: error: 'getLightSensorData' was not declared in this scope

Comment: No, I mean the filenames that should be part of those messages. What happened to them?

Comment: You've changed your story again. It was "measuremant_t" before; now it's "measurement_t". Don't retype (parts of) the compiler output. Copy/paste it all (in your question, not a comment).

Comment: Just compiled the code, Compiled successfully!I think you are compiling wrong file.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ : I have edited the post and included the minimal version

Comment: @LászlóFrank How are code lines like `bool radioOk = myRadio.begin();` relevant for the problem? Explain in depth please, or narrow further.

Comment: @melpomene : I removed the filenames, they are the same:. 
C:\My Projects\Visual Studio Projects\IOT\WirelessLightSensor\WirelessLightSensor.ino 6 
I can't post the full output here...

Comment: Yes, you can and should post the full output.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ : the code you quoted is not relevant at all, please could you look at the modified post and the minimal version included.

Comment: @melpomene : could we please focus on the minimal code version ?

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to compile this as `C` rather than `C++`?  That might in some way account for those error messages.

Comment: @LászlóFrank I am. Where are the error messages?

Comment: @melpomene : 
Error compiling project sources
Debug build failed for project 'test'
test.ino: 2:1: error: 'measurement_t' does not name a type
   measurement_t getLightSensorData()

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  2:1: error: 'measurement_t' does not name a type  C:\Users\Lacko\Documents\Arduino\test\test.ino 2

Comment: The code compiles, Check this     https://ibb.co/hibPtv

Comment: @LászlóFrank Well, your [_"minimal example"_](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d7eb835894729c65) doesn't reproduce the problem, that's why I'm complaining.

Comment: @LászlóFrank Dude. Relevant information needs to go into the question itself, not down here hidden in the comments.

Comment: Use 'struct measurement_t getLightSensorData()'

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, user64322 : I updated the post and inserted a picture of Visual Studio exhibiting the isue (link right below the minimal code version)

Comment: @LászlóFrank What's actually so hard to understand about a _[MCVE]_?

Comment: @user64322 : your're right, I had to use struct measurement_t getLightSensorDate() ! At last, problem resolved for now.  Many thanks ! 
Could you also explain what is the difference ?

Comment: @user64322 You suspect a c compiler is used here? I doubt so. Is that special for arduino?

Comment: @LászlóFrank Your screenshot shows the file from line 3 onwards. The error message refers to line 2.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ : look at the picture in the post if you don't believe me. My example was Minimal, Complete and Verifiable. Why us that so difficult to understand ? By the way, issue has been resolved.

Comment: @melpomene : line 1-2 were empty, it just was scrolled down a bit, sorry for that

Comment: @LászlóFrank It's not a question if I _believe_ you or not. You're in charge to pinpoint something reproducible for us.

Comment: Thanks you all guys for your instant and precise help !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You had to use

```
struct measurement_t getLightSensorData()
{
  int sensorValue = analogRead(LIGHTSENSOR_PIN);
  measurement_t m(1, sensorValue);
  return m;
}
```

You might have outdated version of Arduino IDE because on my IDE it compiled without the use of `struct` keyword.

Comment: I have Arduino IDE 1.8.1 installed and as far as I can see this is the latest. On the other hand I am using vMicro from VS2015, maybe it has something to do with this strange behavior.